# Php get url between special characters

Tags: php, facebook, url

```
$url = 'hxxx://www.xxxx.com/#node=xxxxxxxx&lasts=5613';
$e=explode('#',$url);
echo $e[count($e)-1];
```

This gives Me output

```
node=xxxxxxxx&lasts=5613
```

i just Want

```
node=xxxxxxxx
```

this in output the url between  # and &

Anyone...

Comment: use regex - this: http://txt2re.com/ for your lazyness ;-)

Comment: just another tip `echo $e[count($e)-1];` is equal to [`echo end($e);`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

captain regex to the rescue:

```
<?php 
$url = 'hxxx://www.xxxx.com/#node=xxxxxxxx&lasts=5613';
$result = array();
preg_match('/#([^\&]+)\&/', $url, $result);
echo $result[1];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 1):

Here the first thing that popped into my head

```
$url = 'hxxx://www.xxxx.com/#node=xxxxxxxx&lasts=5613';
$e = explode('#', $url);
$params = array();
parse_str(end($e), $params);
print_r($params);
```

You will have an array `$params` with `node` and `lasts`

```
echo $params['node'];
```

Will give you what you want

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $url = 'hxxx://www.xxxx.com/#node=xxxxxxxx&lasts=5613';
    $arr = parse_url($url);

   $arr = explode("&",$arr['fragment']);

   $val = $arr[0]
```

Comment: This will create an array with 'fragment' which is basically the same issue he already has

Comment: yes from fragment value just split by & and get first index

Comment: Might want to put that in your answer :)